# Orchard - Search & Indexing issue

Tags: lucene, indexing, orchardcms, field

I have a project completed with Orchard CMS. The all functionalities are implemented through modules. Search module was also working till a few days ago, but suddenly it is stopped to working, "without any reason". 
The issue is that I can not rebuild/update indexes. When I run indexing, it will only index default list of fields (id, title, body, format, type, author, created, published, modified, culture) but my custom fields are not indexed.
I tried everything but without any success. I tried:
- Deleting Indexing/Search folder with all files
- Reinstalling Search/Indexing/Lucene modules
- Rebuilding and rebuilding indexes....
- Clearing solution and rebuilding...

**I didn't extend any of Orchard modules, they are the same as when I downloaded them.**

Any advice on this one...?

**P.S. Yes, I already checked custom fields thats need to be indexed. :)**
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think the index is corrupted, delete `App_data\Sites\Default\Search.settings.xml` and `App_data\Sites\Default\Indexes`, then restart the app pool. You should then be able to rebuild the index.

Apparently you already did this, but for others who may not have, you also need to check the fields you want indexed under Settings/Search. This will include the fields in search.

But for the fields to be included in search, they need to be indexed first. For this, you need to go to Content/Content Types and edit the content type the fields are on. Check "index this content type for search". Also deploy the settings for each field you want indexed, and check "include in the index".

Comment: Thank you. I have done all that but still not working. It is working only for default fields, but custom fields are ignored.

Comment: In the field settings, have you checked that this field is included in the index ?

Comment: Hey, did you fix this? I have got exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run the "Recipe" to create the "Search" index.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Search + Lucene + Indexing works with Text Fields but not Numeric Fields.

Answer (score -1):

When the search feature is enabled, the Settings screen in the dashboard displays the fields that will be queried from the index (listed on the Search screen).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubRgo.png)